# Recording Guns Indoors

Tags: gunshot, record, indoor, sfx

I have the pleasure of being able to record a gun (powder charge only) being fired inside of a large concrete room.  I have read a lot about shooting outdoors from Chuck Russom, but I'm wondering if there is anything specific I should look for inside.

The other thing is I have only 2, maybe 4 inputs to record the effect.  This is being done on the tail end of an ADR session and we're just going to get what we can in the spare time after the actors are done.  About 90% of the SFX needed were recorded on site, really all we're missing are punches and gunshots.

I have a Schoeps MK41, AT 897 shorty shotgun, 2 AGK small capsule mics, and a few contact mics that I've made and coated in handle dip.  I may be able to ask for a few more mic rentals if I can justify them.

I was thinking of one of the AKGs near the gun for the initial shot, the Schoeps about 20 feet out to get the distant perspective, a contact mic directly on the gun barrel, and one more AKG maybe 12 - 15 feet out from the barrel.

Any thoughts would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never recorded guns indoors, but the technique should be similar or the same as outdoors (it will just sound different).  It may be louder than outdoors, or at least sound louder.

Assuming you have 4 channels, and given your mic selections, I would suggest, as a **starting point**:

AT Shotgun - behind the shooter, aimed over his shoulder down-range.  10-15 feet back.  You'll have to find how close you can get the mic before it sounds bad, it might be closer than 10 feet, might be further back than 15.  I've never worked with that mic.

Schoeps - Off to the side of the shooter, pointed at the gun, not ahead of the barrel.  You'll have to experiment to find a good distance.

Your other mics, if they are a pair, try them in XY stereo and put them the furthest out to get a distant perspective.  If you end up putting them ahead of the gun barrel, you may get a better sound facing them away from the gun.

I would never put a mic on the gun barrel, they get hot!  If the gun has an interesting mechanism sound, you can try a contact mic or lav mic near the mechanism.

Don't forget to experiment as much as you can, that is the only way to find the perfect placement for the environment you are in and the weapon you are firing.

Answer (score 4):

It might be interesting to place a microphone a few feet (maybe 4 or 5) from and aimed directly into a corner of the room. You might be able to capture some interesting reflections if you've got the time.

Comment: Good idea!  I'll see if I can get an interesting echo.